# Is it possible to send Emails using only the REST API

Tags: rest-api

There are a couple of similar questions on StackExchange but the only answers reference APEX code.  Is it actually possible to send an email using only the REST API?

I am looking for a REST-ful way to achieve the same result as clicking on "Send Email" from the Contact view and selecting an Email Template.

Comment: Do you mean to use an external email API?

Comment: Did you find out?

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17345/is-it-possible-to-send-an-email-via-the-rest-api#

You can look above link.

Comment: I'll add my desperate voice also: did a solution ever arise? I need to do the exact same (email a contact using a template with REST.)

APEX is not an option as I need this to be universal, and not for one particular client.

SOAP looks outdated and not well-supported, and also tied into one org's WSDL too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are looking for is [Salesforce Actions](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_action.pdf). They are accessible through the REST api and you can send an email either directly by specifying the recipients, body, and subject for a "Simple Email Action", or by selecting an email alert and the related sObject Id for a "Email Alert Action". For example, if you had an email alert on the Contact object in your org named `Hello`, you could have it sent using the REST api by calling

```
$ curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer SessionId' -H 'X-PrettyPrint:1' -d @jsonfile -H 'Content-Type: application/json' BaseURL/services/data/v36.0/actions/custom/emailAlert/Contact/NameSpace__Hello
```

./jsonfile

```
{
  "inputs" : [
    {
      "SObjectRowId" : "0039000001lGlON"
    },
    {
      "SObjectRowId" : "0039000001lGlTu"
    }
  ]
}
```