# Triggered Send email to multiple recipients via REST API

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, rest-api, email

Is there a way to send an email to multiple recipients via a the RESTful API call. Here is our current JSON we are using for sending emails to a single user.

```
{
    "From": {
        "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "EmailTest"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "recipient@email.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "recipient@email.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "content" : "hello"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only answers to this I could find are a couple of years old.

Comment: I see you have the marketing-cloud tag on your post. Did you need to use that, or would a standard salesforce REST api call work as well?

Comment: related:  [Is it possible to send an email via the REST API?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17345/is-it-possible-to-send-an-email-via-the-rest-api?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST API does allow you to send to multiple recipients in one go, you achieve this by passing an array of subscribers and appending sendBatch to the endpoint URL.

There are a few posts that detail the syntax - eg. [Multiple sends through MessageDefinitionSends](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28110/multiple-sends-through-messagedefinitionsends)

Annoyingly, the documentation doesn't seem to offer anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a new way to send email by calling the salesforce REST api, you could use the [Salesforce Actions](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_action.pdf) for sending emails which became available in api version 32.0.

```
$ curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer SessionId' -H 'X-PrettyPrint:1' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @jsonfile BaseURL/services/data/v36.0/actions/standard/emailSimple
```

./jsonfile

```
{
  "inputs" : [
    {
      "emailBody" : "This is the body of the email",
      "emailAddresses" : "user1@email.com,user2@email.com",
      "emailSubject" : "An email from salesforce",
      "senderType" : "CurrentUser"
    }
  ]
}
```

Emails sent this way will count against the "DailyWorkflowEmails" and "DailyApiRequests" limits.