# Send email via API requests without accessing SalesForce UI

Tags: email, api

I am new to SalesForce. Currently investigating possibility to use SelesForce as Email provider. I am wondering if it is possible to send email via API requests without accessing SalesForce UI. As far as understood from API doc Email template should be created in SalesFoce UI and further referenced in API requests.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Salesforce is not meant to be an email service provider and you will run into many limitations if you try it to use it that way.

Comment: David, thank you for your answer. I am currently gathering information to asses the feasibility of using Sales Force as messaging service provider. The goal is to figure out if it is possible to send email message using API and track message delivery status using API. Do you know if it is possible in theory? Also you've mentioned that we might run into many limitations. Could you perhaps point to couple of them? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can send email through Apex class using Single email messaging. Once you create apex class for sending email you can schedule the class to send email on time defined by you.

You can schedule a class to send email hourly/daily/weekly/monthly

You can make API request as well to send email.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am interested it it is possible to pass html body and subject of the email to  SOAP or REST API and send it to recipient. In case yes, could you point me to API requests that I should use, thank you.

Comment: You may look into this - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/112093/triggered-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-via-rest-api

Comment: and this https://blog.webnersolutions.com/salesforce-singleemailmessage-rest-api-and-c-consumer

Comment: Would it be possible to track message delivery status of those emails?